# Symfony Doctrine - Prevent slug from being null

Tags: symfony, doctrine, slug

I have a Article table where the only field that can contain text is `content`

From that i'm trying to get a slug

```php
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64, unique=true)
     * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"content"})
     */
    private $slug;
```

By mistake I found out that if I try to use some emoji's slug becomes null

I have tried to check if the slug is null in the setter method without success

```php
public function setSlug(string $slug): self
    {
        if ($slug)
        {
            $this->slug = $slug;
        }
        else {
            $r = substr(md5(rand()), 0, 7);
            $this->slug = $r;
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

MySQL 5.7 , PHP 7.2, symfony 4.2, charset utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Any ideeas ?
My symfony skills are ... begginer's level :)

Comment: I am seeing the GitHub page about slug and in the examples, they don't use setSlug.

Comment: By mistake I found out that if I try to use some emoji's slug becomes null, thats why i'm trying to check if is null ...

Answer (score 1):

use `@Assert` in your entity to allow only alphaNumeric value and check if it is not blank:

```
/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 * @Assert\Type(type="alnum")
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64, unique=true)
 * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"content"})
 */
private $slug;
```

see the doc here: [Symfony Validation doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html)

Comment: you don't understand ... a bug from Sluggable can't parse emoji, therefore slug becomes null, so i need a workaround